# wasRecentlyCreated in PHP not detecting newly created campaign

Tags: php, database, forms, if-statement

I'm currently working on a form to create a campaign and would like for the form to detect whether the user has already submitted the form and to display an alternative message.

I have the following if statement set up to determine what message to display to the user:

```
if ($campaign->wasRecentlyCreated) {
    $response['message'] = 'Campaign edited successfully';
} else {
    $response['message'] = 'Campaign created successfully';
}
```

I've tried other suggestions that I've also seen on stack overflow such as the following:

```
$campaign->exists === false 
$campaign->getDirty
$campaign->getChanges
```

with the if statement stated earlier in the post, it's outputting the first message "Campaign edited successfully". This message displays, even though I haven't yet created a campaign. When I try submitting the form again and again, I get the same output message over and over again. Each time I click the save button, the entry is being saved into the database.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Additional Code:

```
    if ($_REQUEST['id']) {
        $campaign = Campaign::find($_REQUEST['id']);
    } else {
        $campaign = new Campaign();
    }

$campaign->name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $campaign->is_draft = $_REQUEST['is_draft'];
        $campaign->is_closed = $_REQUEST['is_closed'];
        $campaign->summary = $_REQUEST['summary'];
        $campaign->requirements = $_REQUEST['requirements'];
        $campaign->additional_details = $_REQUEST['additional_details'];
        $campaign->key_information = $_REQUEST['key_information'];
        $campaign->opportunity_type = $_REQUEST['opportunity_type'];
        $campaign->number_of_stores = $_REQUEST['number_of_stores'];
        $campaign->logo_image = $_REQUEST['logo_image'];
        $campaign->started_at = Carbon::parse($_REQUEST['started_at']);
        $campaign->ended_at = Carbon::parse($_REQUEST['ended_at']);

        // only set this when saving a new campaign
        if ($campaign->wasRecentlyCreated()) {
            $campaign->member_id = $member->id;
        }

        $campaign->save();

        $members = $_REQUEST['members'];

        // only do this for a newly created campaign
        if ($campaign->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            if (!array_key_exists($member->id, (array) $members)) {
                $members[$member->id] = CampaignMember::ADMIN;
            }
        }

        $campaign->addMembers($members);
        $campaign->addCategories($_REQUEST['categories']);

        if ($campaign->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $response['message'] = 'Campaign edited successfully';
        } else {
            $response['message'] = 'Campaign created successfully';
        }
```

Comment: Those are most likely functions, not properties, so you're missing the `()`. `$campaign->wasRecentlyCreated()`

Comment: When I add the "()", I get the following error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::wasRecentlyCreated()

Comment: Can you show how you're defining `$campaign`?

Comment: You're still not showing `$campaign = .....`

Comment: apologies, should be there now

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I was wrong, `wasRecentlyCreated` is a property, not a method, as is `exists`. However, `isDirty()` and `getChanges()` are methods. `wasRecentlyCreated` only updates when the model is saved, so is false at the time you're checking it. The same goes for `exists`. I would suggest updating the member_id if it's empty or if `$campaign->id` is empty, and then check those properties for the message after it's saved.

Comment: I've updated the code to show you what I have after the save

Comment: In your code $campaign->wasRecentlyCreated is always null. So script always will go to else branch

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why it would always be null